# Vue Class Component property not defined on instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-class-components

I have the problem that my UI is somehow not updating after the applications fetches some data from the sever backend.

I have the following code:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="restaurant">
    <div class="center logo-container">
        <img class="img-fit" v-bind:src="'/api/restaurant/logo/' + restaurant.id" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <h2 class="title center dm-text-header">{{ restaurant.name }}</h2>
    <h4 class="subheading center">{{ restaurant.address.street }}, {{ restaurant.address.city }}</h4>     
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios';
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { Tag } from "./Tag";
import { Restaurant } from "./Restaurant";

@Options({
  props: {
  }
})
export default class Menu extends Vue {  
  // hardcoded for testing 
  restaurantId =  "8ykw9ljq";   

  tagUrl = "/api/menu/" + this.restaurantId + "/tags";
  restaurantUrl = "/api/restaurant/" + this.restaurantId;

  restaurant!: Restaurant;
  tags: Tag[] = [];

  mounted() {
    // get tags
    this.getTags();
    // get restaurant
    this.getRestaurant();
  }

  getRestaurant(): void {
    axios.get<Restaurant>(this.restaurantUrl)
    .then(res => {
      this.restaurant = res.data;
    });
  }

  getTags(): void {
    axios.get(this.tagUrl)
    .then(res => {
      this.tags = res.data;
    });
  }

}
</script>
```

I verified that the backend actually serves the correct restaurant and logged the results after the axios call finishes. The problem is that the DOM is not updated. If I add the following to the  the DOM is upadated:

```
<template>
...
  <div>
    {{tags}}
  </div>
<template>
```

It seems to me that vue somehow only updated the DOM if it recognizes changes to the already initialized empty array but not the currently uninitialized restaurant object.

I further get a warning:
`[Vue warn]: Property "restaurant" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.` on the `v-if` what I kind of find strange because that is the exact reason it is there. How do I need to initialize the restaurant, such that the update through axios is correctly recognized by vue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a Typescript [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) with `null`:

```
restaurant: Restaurant | null = null;
```

---

From the Vue Class Component [docs](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#data):

> Note that if the initial value is undefined, the class property will not be reactive which means the changes for the properties will not be detected

and

> To avoid this, you can use null value or use data hook instead:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  // `message` will be reactive with `null` value
  message = null

  // See Hooks section for details about `data` hook inside class.
  data() {
    return {
      // `hello` will be reactive as it is declared via `data` hook.
      hello: undefined
    }
  }
}
```